# How to specify type that can be either integer or string

Tags: python, typing, function-parameter

I have a function that its parameter should be **integer** or **string**.

```
from typing import int,str

def MyFunc(arg:int) -> None:
    print(arg)
```

but I want to know how to write it to tell the user arg can be both int and str?

Comment: That's why `print` and `input` exists.

Comment: No dude. It's just an example and my function is something else

Comment: oh, ok, sorry..

Answer (score 26):

First of all, I don't think you need to use the import as `int` and `str` are base types.

Apart from that my solution would be (python3)

```
from typing import Union

def MyFunc(arg:Union[int, str]) -> None:
    print(arg)
```

This is the standard approach, that would also allow you to use type checkers like `mypy`. The `Union` keyword indicates that your argument can be either one of the types inside the square brackets.

Comment: Thanks. But Can you tell me what is the difference between   arg:Union[int, str]    and    arg:[int, str]?

Comment: Also I knew that I didn't need to import typing but you know SO users. They just think i dont know what is typing so they close my question and refer it to another :)

Comment: basically stuff after the : symbol is interpreted as a type for python, and not used at runtime. You can put most stuff there and it won't complain. Using Union is the better approach because it's a universal way to define types and it can be parsed by type checkers. having arg: "int or str" cannot be checked so other than documentation is useless

Answer (score -3):

One option is

```
def MyFunc(arg:"int or str") -> None:
    print(arg)
```

Another option is

```
def MyFunc(arg:[int,str]) -> None:
    print(arg)
```

Comment: Thank you. But your second example doesn't mean that arg type is list?

Comment: Normally, if you want to specify that the argument is a list, you write `def MyFunc(arg: list) -> None`

Comment: Aha. Thank you very much. :)